# NodeJS, Assigning Name/getting value of Jade Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobile-website, pug, express

I populate a table within a form from a Mongo Database. I want the user to be able to select one or many checkboxes and then determine which items were selected from the table. One part of the problem is that I am not sure how to name the checkboxes as they are dynamically created. I also do not know how to read the checkbox property.

I am using ExpressJS and Jade. I can populate the table no problem, but have no idea how to then communicate which items were selected.

Here is my jade

```
    h1 index view

    form  (method='post', action='/customers/check')
      fieldset
        legend Add a Customer
    div.clearfix
      -if(docs.length)
      table(style="border-left:1px solid black")
        tr
          th First Name
          th Last Name
          th "Hidden" 
            each first in docs
              tr
               td #{first.first} 
               td #{first.surname}
               td #{first.group}
               td
                 div.input
                    input(type="checkbox", name=(#{first.box}), unchecked=     (true===true ? "checked" : "")).checkbox
        div.actions
          input(type='submit', value='Save', class='btn primary')
          button(type='reset', class='btn') Cancel
```

My Mongo Database has four properties (first, surname, group, and i added box in attempt to solve this problem
In the big picture what i am doing is taking a String input, then rendering a view with this table and I want to store the String input and whatever elements from the table that are selected into another mongoDB with two properties ( string and complex object)  please saveee meeee!!! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah got it, was dancing around the solution the whole time

```
  h1 index view

 form(method='post', action='/customers/check')
fieldset
    legend Add a Customer
    div.clearfix
        -if(docs.length)
            table(style="border-left:1px solid black")
                tr
                    th First Name
                    th Last Name
                    th "Hidden" 
                        each first in docs
                            tr
                                td #{first.first} 
                                td #{first.surname}
                                td #{first.group}
                                td
                                    div(data-role='fieldcontain')   
                                        fieldset(data-type='vertical', data-role='controlgroup')                                           
                                            label(for='showpass') show password
                                            input(id='showpass',type='checkbox', name='#{first.id}')
    div.actions
        input(type='submit', value='Save', class='btn primary')
        button(type='reset', class='btn') Cancel
```

and my server side I put the checked values into an array called "arr", here that is

```
     app.post('/customers/check', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        var locks = req.body;
        var arr = Object.keys(locks);
        console.log(arr);   
        res.redirect('/customers')
});
```